# Ошибка Function implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation

Tags: typescript

```
interface Props {
  nameRu?: string,
  id?: number,
  nestedChildren?: Props[]
}

export const getData = <T extends Props>(data: T[]) => data.map(item => ({
  label: item.nameRu,
  value: item.id,
  ...((item.nestedChildren && !isEmpty(item.nestedChildren))
    ? { nestedChildren: getData(item.nestedChildren) }
    : {}),
}))
```

Есть такая функция, ts выдает такую ошибку.

> Function implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.

Может есть у кого соображения как это испправить?

Answer (score 0):

Ну если просто избавиться от ошибки, то можно так

```js
export const getData = <T extends Props>(data: T[]): object => data.map(item => ({
 label: item.nameRu,
 value: item.id,
 ...((item.nestedChildren && !isEmpty(item.nestedChildren))
     ? { nestedChildren: getData(item.nestedChildren) }
     : {}),
}))
```

А вообще по-хорошему надо вместо object прописать интерфейс/тип, возвращаемый данной функцией

Answer (score 0):

Указать возвращаемый тип:

```
interface Props {
  nameRu?: string,
  id?: number,
  nestedChildren?: Props[]
}

type Data = {
  label?: string,
  value?: number,
  nestedChildren?: Data[]
}

export const getData = <T extends Props>(data: T[]): Data[] => data.map(item => ({
  label: item.nameRu,
  value: item.id,
  ...((item.nestedChildren && !isEmpty(item.nestedChildren))
    ? { nestedChildren: getData(item.nestedChildren) }
    : {}),
}))
```